# User group and access level

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, user-groups, access, joomla-user-groups

I want to ask about user group and access level. Since I'm new in Joomla, I still a bit confuse to make the user access. I hope someone can help me. Below I have 6 different menu and each will have upload and upload list button. What I want to make is 1 menu can be access to 1 user group. Please help me..

[image]

The 6 menu above will have the upload and uploaded list button  each.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code for us to review?

Comment: I'm not using any coding. I try to make it using Joomla ACL but it quite confusing.

Comment: I try to make the new user group but it doesn't seem to work. I make a new user group for process and also user group for proposal. But still the process user group can see proposal user group button. Please help

Comment: I am new to Joomla as well and I am not likely to give you the support that you require, I'm merely asking for any additional details that may help other volunteers to better understand your issue.

Comment: Before this I'm make the portal from scratch so I can write the code base on user role tho show or not the upload button. However, I want to make the same using Joomla ACL but the ACL is little bit confusing for beginner like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a user group for each menu item.
Then, create an Access Level for each menu item, and assign it to its corresponding user group.
When you create the menu items, set its Access to the appropriate Access View Level

**Steps:**

1. Create the user group "Process"
2. Create the Access Level "Process" and tick/select the user group "Process" to give users belonging to this group this access level.
3. Create the menu item "Process" and set its Access to "Process"
4. Repeat 1 to 3 for each menu item

This way, any user belongs to ONLY one group of them, will see only its menu item.